# Addressing computers via ipv6 on local network

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I'm very confused about how to address a computer on my local network via ipv6. I am writing a server which is meant to support both ipv4 and ipv6. Now I have don an ifconfig and gotten my ipv4 local ip address, however I get `inet6 addr: fe80::224:d7ff:fe3e:db44/64 Scope:Link` for the ipv6. From what I have read I cannot use this to address the box on my local network right? I guess I just don't quite understand the whole scoping stuff for ipv6 and if someone could explain it to me like I was 5 that would be great. Will I not be able to address it because of how the network is set up?

Just in case it helps I have a dlink dir-601 as my main router.

Answer (score 0):

Link Local Scope means that this address is only valid in your subnet and it is not routed. So if your server shall only be accessed from clients in your subnet, you can use this address. If your server shall be accessible from outside you local subnet, you need a unique local address, a site local address or a global address (depending on who should be able to access your server).

Comment: So when I try to do a command like this: `$ nc -6 fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:166 25665` how come it never actually connects to the server? Like the server box doesn't receive any packets, I was watching with wireshark. from what I can tell being as how both boxes are on the same subnet I should be able to do that no?

Comment: What does netstat -a on the Server say? Is there really someone listening on the port? What are the IPs of the Client and the Server?